# Filechooser only showing files and not allowing the user to create their own

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Following the oracle tutorial, this code should create a file chooser:

```
public File getFileAddress() {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    //chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
       return chooser.getSelectedFile();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Which should look like this:

[image]

Yet, working on a mac, I get this:
[image]

When what I want to get is this:
[image]

So how do I get the thing I want with java, since it seems like it's not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `showOpenDialog` on your JFileChooser. In order to show a Save As tetbox, you probably want to use `showSaveDialog`

```
public File getFileAddress() {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    //chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    int returnVal = chooser.showSaveDialog(this);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
       return chooser.getSelectedFile();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Generally speaking when opening a file, you don't want to let the user create their own file, as this may lead to complications regarding IOExceptions if and when you decide to read from it, thus I assume that it is making that option on OpenDialogs.

To restrict the JFileChooser to certain file tyes, you can use a [FileNameExtensionFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html) you jut need to put

```
chooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("RTF FIles", ".rtf"));
```

after your JFileChooser creation.

To ensure this file type on a save file, you will have to manually fix it, uing a bit on String manipulation:

```
String fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
if(!fileName.endWith(".rtf"))fileName += ".rtf";
return new File(fileName);
```

Comment: Thank you! Just one quick other question: Is there a way to insure that the file given has .rtf at the end? Or do I have to check manually? So can I have it add .rtf if the user does not add it?

Comment: Added a bit on FileFilters, and ensuring file types.

Comment: it still lets you enter a non-rtf name because "All FIles" is still an option with RTF Files. Nevermind

Comment: chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false); Should remove that option.